# Laravel duplicates join on production

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join, duplicates

I have a code where Eloquent query builder joins the ManyToOne tables articles and users.
The code looks like:

```
$model = Article::with('user')->select('articles.*'));
```

and then the model filters the user name

```
$model = $model->join('users', 'articles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->where('users.name', 'like', "%$value%");
```

This throws me an error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique
> table/alias: 'users' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from
> `articles` inner join `users` on `articles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
> inner join `users` on `articles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where
> `users`.`name` like %may% and `users`.`name` like %may% and
> `articles`.`deleted_at` is null)

Look at the duplicate inner join on users table and also duplicate where clause.

The same code on localhost works fine and create sql:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `articles` inner join `users` on `articles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `users`.`name` like '%may%' and `articles`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Original code is here: https://github.com/camohub/laravel-datagrid-example/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/DefaultController.php#L25

and the live error is here: https://laravel-datagrid.tatrytec.eu/?chgrid-filter-username=may&chgrid-perPage=25

I dont understand. It looks like some database setting is wrong.
Hope somebody knows what happened there. Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:** The issue is caused by PHP version. Production is lower 7.4.3 than localhost 7.4.19

Comment: add an alias to one of those users tables and use it in your query.. you cannot use the same alias in multiple joins

Comment: Dont understand. On localhost it works fine. What is the problem on production?

Comment: there must be some discrepancy in your environments.. you can clearly see in the error that the query builder is trying to join the same table twice ... without having more details about your DB model and other stuff, it's very hard to debug..  the problem is def somewhere in misalinged environmental setup :)

Comment: Looks like you join the users table twice [here](https://github.com/camohub/laravel-datagrid-example/blob/48812e4b9fe7de2c2e958fdce0fb6f1ef4163ab8/app/Http/Controllers/DefaultController.php#L70) and [here](https://github.com/camohub/laravel-datagrid-example/blob/48812e4b9fe7de2c2e958fdce0fb6f1ef4163ab8/app/Http/Controllers/DefaultController.php#L76). Maybe you can just remove the second join?

Comment: No the filter is called only if it is active. Still lost in it. :(

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to write an envelope above the Eloquent query builder. Here it is https://github.com/camohub/laravel-datagrid/blob/master/src/QueryBuilder.php